# MariaDB veryslow Inserts Query/Import via Dbeaver

Tags: mariadb, insert, csv

I have a MariaDB server that via DBeaver is getting very slows insert times.
Tables with 10.000 lines only is getting imported in 2minutes

The DB Manager is trying to import CSVs, some with only 80mb and it's this slow.
I tried making some changes to the server configuration but it stills slow.
This is the server my.cnf

```
[client]
port=*****
socket=/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock

[mysqld_safe]
socket=/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock

[mysqld]
user=mysql
pid-file=/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.pid
socket=/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock
port=*****
basedir=/usr
datadir=/var/lib/mysql
tmpdir=/tmp
lc-messages-dir=/usr/share/mysql
log_error=/var/log/mysql/error.log

symbolic-links=0
local-infile=0

skip-external-locking
key_buffer_size = 256M
max_allowed_packet = 2048M
table_open_cache = 256
sort_buffer_size = 1M
read_buffer_size = 1M
read_rnd_buffer_size = 4M
myisam_sort_buffer_size = 64M
thread_cache_size = 8
query_cache_size= 50M
tmp_table_size = 200M
max_heap_table_size = 200M
 

#innodb_use_native_aio = 0
innodb_file_per_table
innodb_flush_log_at_trx_commit = 0
sync_binlog=0


max_connections=2000
max_user_connections=500
wait_timeout=10
interactive_timeout=50
long_query_time=5

!includedir /etc/mysql/conf.d/
!includedir /etc/mysql/mariadb.conf.d/
```

The server has 4 cores, that even during the import it doesn't take 15% of usage. And 8gb of Ram, now using 1,7GB.
The network connection with the PC of the DB manager is getting something like 50kbps~100kbps on the transactions.
So I don't think that it's the machine the problem.

Comment: What is SQL being performed by DBeaver?

Comment: What is the performance when you import a csv using "load data" or mysqlimport?  What if you transfer a csv to the DB system and issue a load data or mysqlimport directly on the server?